# How to check syntax error in bash scripts using python test case?

Tags: python-2.7

I tried to write that code, in a following way:

```
***subprocess.Popen(['python','../somescript.sh',"-h"],shell=True)***
```

But it does not work.

Comment: There's a major problem here. It looks like you're trying to execute a bash/shell script using the python interpreter... that'll never work. Maybe this is more what you're looking for: `subprocess.Popen(['bash','-x', '../somescript.sh',"-h"],shell=True)`. See man page for what `bash -x` is all about.

Comment: It works actually but "-h" did not work. It works with "-n" to check syntax error. And you were right I was making mistakes and writing 'python' instead of 'bash' because it is a bash script.